# Akka-Http: What can be shared between client and server?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

To start a server with Akka-Http, one roughly does this:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
Http().bindAndHandle(routes, webHost, webPort)
```

And to use the request-level client:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
```

Out of the 3 common resources - namely `ActorSystem`, `ActorMaterializer` and `HttpExt` - which ones can be safely shared by both the server and the client in the same application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can all be safely shared and are designed to be used that way.  The only caveat is that if you wanted different threading characteristics for your client vs server, it would require different actor systems.

Comment: Agreed, in most applications you can (and should) treat the `ActorSystem` as a singleton. The `HttpExt` is directly associated with the `ActorSystem`, it is not required to keep track of it separately. Usually one `Materializer` is enough for most applications as well (but you can create additional ones if separation or multiple configurations are required).

Answer (score 0):

IN the above example the uri address akka.io is client address or server address.